# Best field type for price field

Tags: mysql, postgresql

What is the best field type for the price in MySQL and PostgreSQL due the date?

`[any number]`.`[always two digits, except when value is 0]`

Comment: oh, it works. Could you add this as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, just delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html) for MySQL. 
PostgreSQL also supports that

Answer (score 0):

`DECIMAL` in both, and no, this is not an "opinion-based question". :)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html - see arbitrary precision types

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like NUMERIC(15,2) for MySQL and the built-in MONEY data type in PostgreSQL.